# What's the name of the chord when I do the Am shape but with the 2nd and 3rd finger on the 4th and the first on the 3rd fret

Tags: guitar, chords

What's the name of the Chord that I play when I do the Am shape but with the 2nd and 3rd finger on the 4th and the first on the 3rd fret?

Comment: 1. At minimum please try to draw the chord diagram. Which strings are being played? 2. What is the motivation for the question? If someone provides you with a chord symbol, would you be able to understand it? I'm sorry, but it appears that you are not very familiar with music theory. What kind of explanation do you need?

Comment: You mean the chord made up from E-A-F#-B-D-E? You could read that as an E dominant 7 without third with 9 and 11. You could also read this as B minor 7 with 11 over E.

Comment: Instead of making us guess what you mean, just give a diagram, like x02210 for open `Am`. Just change the numbering for whatever you've changed.

Comment: https://www.guitar-chord.org/how-to-read-short-notation.html

Comment: After you give the fingering details, also include the chords before and after. If those before/after chords are straight forward, there is a better change to give a good explanation of the chord in question. Without before/after there is no harmonic context and you'll get half a dozen different jazz chord symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the standard beginner's Am shape (first finger on the 2nd string, first fret):

- The standard shape gives you the notes (from the bottom) E-A-E-A-C-E.
- Moving the whole shape up two frets gives you E-A-F#-B-D-E. Having E on both the bottom and top strings strongly implies an E-chord, so the most appropriate name for this chord would be E9sus4.

Comment: Agreed it sounds like a dominant 7th (9th) chord, although the sus4 bit is low in the mix. Voicing is not wonderful, though.

Answer (score 0):

The classic cowboy chord of Am is fingered on the 1st and 2nd frets.

An Am chord shape moved up to the 3rd and 4th fret would technically be a chord known as 'F#sus(b6)'.

Comment: It’s just a Bm with the 5th in the bass, as long as no open strings are involved.

Comment: That's a more sublime way of saying it, John. Yes.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - guess the 5th string is still open, as is the 6th. And the top!

Comment: @Tim actually the OP didn’t specify about open strings and also didn’t respond to the many comments posted on the question, typical for a first timer.

Comment: @Sparquelito …although I also like the ring of F#+sus4…